# Can you upgrade to Windows 8 from a Trial (unregistered) version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8

Can I upgrade Windows 8 on a trial version of a previous Windows release? Or does the previous release have to be "verified?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the upgrade version will not work with a trial version of any previous Windows OS.

As per the [Windows 8 Upgrade terms and conditions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions), you need a valid base license for Windows XP, Vista, or 7 in order to use an upgrade copy of Windows 8.